# package does not exist while importing

Tags: java, import, package

I have maze and mdp packages in the same root. I imported package mdp into maze :

```
    import mdp.Action ;
```

but I receive package not exists error !!! 
Where am I mistaking ?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: These are two different project. You have to include depended project in the classpath or create the JAR of second project and include it in dependencies of first project.

Comment: "*I have maze and mdp packages in the same root*" no you don't, they are in separate projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create maze.jar and add it to current project library. Both are different projects, you cannot import it like you are trying to do.